# Express, NodeMailer, React: Sending email with values from form

Tags: node.js, express, post, fetch, nodemailer

I am attempting to use Nodemailer to send emails from a contact form on my site. I have a simple Express server sending the data via SMTP. My front-end is React and I have an onSubmit function that is taking care of the POST request as well as implementing a Google Recaptcha.

I am able to submit the form and successfully log the values in the input boxes. Nodemailer is successfully sending the email via SMTP and I am receiving the email. However, when the email is received all of the form data is undefined. The data from the form in my front-end is being logged to Nodejs and I can see the values, but in the email the values are undefined.

Here is my onSubmit handler that takes care of the POST requests:

```
function onSubmit(values) {
    //ref for recaptcha
    const token = reRef.current;
    reRef.current.reset();

    // Data from form that I am attempting to POST and send in the nodemailer email
    const postData = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        mode: "no-cors",
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            name: values.name,
            company: values.company,
            phone: values.phone,
            email: values.email,
            heardAboutUs: values.heardAboutUs,
            region: values.region,
            message: values.howWeCanHelp
        }),
    };

    // Handles form POST request
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/send', postData)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); 

   const captchaOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        mode: "no-cors"
   }

   const secret = 'nunyabidness';
   const sitekey = 'nunyabidness';

   //Handles recaptcha 
   fetch(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret}&response=${sitekey}`, captchaOptions)
   .then(response =>  () => {
       let data = response.json;
       console.log(data)
   })
   .catch(err => console.log('Captcha error : ' + err))
}
```

Here is my Express server:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const { response } = require('express');

const app = express();

// Public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact', {layout: false});
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const output = `
        <h2>New Request a Demo Contact</h2>
         // All these values are undefined in the email
        <ul>
            <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
            <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
            <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
            <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
            <li>Heard About Us: ${req.body.heardAboutUs}</li>
            <li>Region: ${req.body.region}</li>
            <li>How We Can Help: ${req.body.message}</li>
        </ul>
    `;

   // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'HOST_HERE',
    port: 25,
    secure: false, 
    ignoreTLS: true,
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
      from: '"Website-Contact Form" <EMAIL_HERE>',
      to: 'EMAIL_RECIPIENT_HERE',
      subject: 'Node Contact Request', 
      html: output
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          res.status(500).send('error');
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

      res.status(200).send('success');
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started'))
```

I removed the emails and keys for privacy.

Why are the form values successfully logging both in the client and node, but are undefined in the email?